# How to set custom event cumulated value as Firebase Remote Config experiment goal?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I am using *Firebase Remote Config* to do A/B tests in my app. I would like to set **value** (`FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE`) of reported **custom event** as one of experiment goals (metrics to track).

Currently custom event occurrence is reported in experiment results but I would like to see cumulated value of this event - similar to built-in *Estimated Total Revenue* objective.

Is it possible to set cumulated value of custom event to be reported as experiment goal or to create 'custom objective' similar to built-in *Estimated Total Revenue*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Firebase support and it's not yet possible to use the custom parameter values as a "Goal".